# PHP - How to fetch posts when the ID of one table has to be identical to another table?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently developing a newsfeed app with php. User's are assigned a location. User's can create posts which are assigned the location of the user. So far the newsfeed is being populated by all posts regardless of location. What I need is to populate the newsfeed by posts where the post location matches the user location.

This is the code that fetches the posts currently, ordering them by their creation date in descending order:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I couldnt get this to work because I forgot to join my users and posts tables. This is the code I have now and I still cant get it to work.

```
  DB::table('posts')
            ->join('users', function ($join) {
             $join->on('users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->where('posts.location', '=', 'users.location');
             });

       $posts = Post::where('posts.location','users.location')
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();






return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    Post::where('location',$userLocation)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Hope it helps.

EDITED answer, as nCrazed suggested, no need to use raw query.

Comment: Why not `where('location', $userLocation)`?

Comment: To elaborate on the question: As far as I can tell, there is no reason to use raw which bypasses parameter binding and since we don't know the origin of the location, potentially introduces an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Fair enough, You are right no particular reason to use raw query, I began for another answer and ended up with this because we do not have enough info for the $users origin.